# Getter on nested objects without having NullPointerException

Tags: java

I have an object as follow :

```
Class A {

B b;
// getters

}

Class B {

C c;
// getters

}

Class C {

D d
// getters

}
```

I want to get value on `A.getB().getC().getD(`) and not to get `NullPointerExceptions`

I want to avoid writting something like :

```
    if (A.getB() == null) {
return null
}
    else if (A.getB().getC()) == null) { 
return null 
}
    else  
return A.getB().getC().getD()
```

Is there a more proper way to do that ?

FYI Optional.ofNullable is not working too.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

Comment: How about setting a default value?

Comment: The default value is null! so it do not work

Comment: Using optional in java 8?

Comment: The optional is not working too

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? What's the problem?

Comment: I m getting NullPointerException

Comment: That means `individual` is null.